# bootstrap popover with html content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get separate the bootstrap popover content from the html attributes like you can do with other components, but I can't get it to work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Popover Example</h3>
    <p>Popovers are not CSS-only plugins, and must therefore be initialized with jQuery: select the specified element and call the popover() method.</p>
    <div class="popover" >
      <a href="#" class="popover-toggle" title="Popover Header" >Toggle popover</a>
        <div class="popover-content">
          Here I am
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();  
   });
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have simple anchor and some div which should not be displayed.

```
<a href="#" id="tglr" class="popover-toggle" title="Popover Header">Toggle popover</a>
<div id="customdiv" style="display: none">
    Here <b>I</b> am
</div>
```

In JS we get our anchor (by id) and install popover on it with 2 options: first 'html' - allows to display html instead of simple text, second specifies content, which obtained from our div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tglr').popover({
        html : true, 
        content: function() {
            return $('#customdiv').html();
        } 
    });  
 });
```

Here is your example https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8529/

One of the issues of your code - you perform $('[data-toggle="popover"]') which will select tags with data-toggle that equals to "popover"), but you have no such tags. If you want to initalize popovers this way you should declare anchor like this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" class="popover-toggle" title="Popover Header">Toggle popover</a>
```

But in your case you have only one link with one custom popover, so it is more logically select it by id.

Comment: sorry for any typos, but my point is that with other bootstrap components, (say drop down menu) you can specify the content separately from the button, by wrapping both elements in a div.  I guess this does not work with pop overs????

Comment: I understand what you want but I don't understand why you want wrap it? What advantages of such way? Do you just want to reach some uniformity and understand logic of bootstrap? As for me in practice it is inconvenient way. In many cases even simple data-content attribute instead of div is enough.

Comment: thanks for understanding!  The reason is partly yes to understand but mainly because we are integrating Ruby with React using Opal.  React does not like having parts of the DOM shoved into a string like this.  It can be done, but it makes react less effecient.